# How Add new value in a Custom Picklist with APEX

Tags: picklist, metadata

I am writing an apex method where I have to add picklist value dynamically with apex code. I have followed many websites but not able to get this. Please check my code below.

```java
public with sharing class updateLec_OnTimeTablecls
{
    
    public static void UpdatePicklistField()
    {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();    
        MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
        customField.fullName = 'Scheduler__c.Lectures__c';       // your object. fields name
        customField.label = 'picklist';                 // label of field.
        customField.type_x = 'Picklist';               // type
        metadataservice.Picklist pt = new metadataservice.Picklist();
        pt.sorted= false;
        metadataservice.PicklistValue two = new metadataservice.PicklistValue(); //new value
        two.fullName= 'second';
        two.default_x=false ;
        metadataservice.PicklistValue three = new metadataservice.PicklistValue(); // new value
        three.fullName= 'third';
        three.default_x=false ;
        pt.picklistValues = new list<metadataservice.PicklistValue>{two,three};  
        customField.picklist = pt ;
        MetadataService.UpdateMetadata ut = new MetadataService.UpdateMetadata(); // here you are updated your value in object.
        ut.currentName='Scheduler__c.Lectures__c';
        ut.metadata= customField;  
        MetadataService.AsyncResult[] results = service.updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.updateMetadata> {ut});
    }
    public static MetadataService.MetadataPort createService()

    {
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
        service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
        service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
        return service;    
    }
}
```

> ERROR:Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: picklist at line 20 column 21

If I comment on line 20, I am getting

> Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: MetadataService.UpdateMetadata at line 21 column 9

Please help!

Comment: What is the usecase and why do you want to handle this using Apex?

Comment: @the_phantom I have to update my picklist field value while I insert a new object record. Let's say, I need to update objects B picklist field value while I insert object A records.

Comment: I am a bit skeptical to answer this as changing metadata from Apex is not a very recommended way. Is this a hard requirement OR there is a chance you can convince your customer to follow a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

You're following outdated examples. The [`Picklist`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm) Metadata API type and corresponding field on `CustomField` were supported [until API 37.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm).

In later API versions, you must instead use the [`valueSet`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm) property and the `ValueSet` type.

The fact that you're getting those errors suggests your Metadata API classes were generated from a WSDL that postdates API 37.0, so you'll want to switch to writing your code based on `ValueSet`.